# processing texture for shape with triangle_strip mode

Tags: java, processing

I want to construct TRIANGLE_STRIP shape with different texture in each sector.
Is it possible to use TRIANGLE_STRIP shape in this case?
I can't understand how to set horizontal and vertical coordinate for the texture mapping in this shape mode because each triangle shares vertex points with each other and because of that I can set horizontal and vertical coordinate for the texture mapping  only for one image.

```
PImage img1, img2, img3, img4, img5;
void setup() {
  size(800, 300, P3D);
  img1 = loadImage("img1.png");
  img2 = loadImage("img2.png");
  ....
  textureMode(NORMAL);
 // textureWrap(REPEAT);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
   beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
   texture(img1);
    vertex(30, 286,0,1);
    vertex(158, 30, 0.5, 0);
    vertex(286, 286,1,1);
    texture(img2);
    vertex(414, 30, ?, ?);
    texture(img3);
    vertex(542, 286, ?, ?);
    texture(img4);
    vertex(670, 30,?,?);
    texture(img4);
    vertex(798, 286,?,?);
    endShape();
}
```

UPD

I wand to acheive the result similar to that animation:
https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/7d7bf511219015.560f42336f0bd.gif

First of all I want to construct complicated object based on TRIANGLE_STRIP or QUAD_STRIP shape mode and after that just change z coordinate of vertexes.

So I just took image with such inscription and cut it on different images for each sector of shape.

If someone knows how to make it in more easy way I will be very thankful for help.

[image: full image]

[image: sector]

Comment: Could you supply the images you're talking about, along with a mockup of the end result you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I added pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a small sketch that simply displays a triangle strip (without any texturing) over the entire space you want to take up. Here's an example that fills the whole screen:

```
void setup() {
  size(300, 200);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(0);
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);

  vertex(0, 200);
  vertex(0, 0);
  vertex(50, 200);
  vertex(100, 0);
  vertex(150, 200);
  vertex(200, 0);
  vertex(250, 200);
  vertex(300, 0);
  vertex(300, 200);

  endShape();
}
```

The goal is to make sure your vertexes cover the area you want your image to cover. You want something that looks like this:

[image]

This will also make it easier to map the vertex coordinates to image texture coordinates.

**Step 2:** Create an image that you want to use as a texture. I'll use this one:

[image]

**Step 3:** For each vertex you're drawing on the screen, figure out where in the image that point is. If a point is in the middle of the screen, then you need to figure out the position of the middle of the image. That's your values for `u` and `v`.

Alternatively, you can use `textureMode(NORMAL)` so you can specify `u` and `v` as normalized values between `0` and `1`. The middle of the image becomes point `(.5, .5)`.

Which approach you take is up to you, but in either case you have to map the screen vertex positions to the image `u, v` positions. I'll use the normalized values here:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(300, 200, P3D);
  img = loadImage("test.png");
  textureMode(NORMAL);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(0);
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);

  texture(img);
  vertex(0, 200, 0, 1);
  vertex(0, 0, 0, 0);
  vertex(50, 200, .16, 1);
  vertex(100, 0, .33, 0);
  vertex(150, 200, .5, 1);
  vertex(200, 0, .66, 0);
  vertex(250, 200, .83, 1);
  vertex(300, 0, 1, 0);
  vertex(300, 200, 1, 1);

  endShape();
}
```

[image]

**Step 4:** Now you can modify the position of one of the vertexes, and you'll morph the image drawn on screen:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(300, 200, P3D);
  img = loadImage("test.png");
  textureMode(NORMAL);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(0);
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);

  texture(img);
  vertex(0, 200, 0, 1);
  vertex(0, 0, 0, 0);
  vertex(50, 200, .16, 1);
  vertex(100, 0, .33, 0);
  vertex(mouseX, mouseY, .5, 1);
  vertex(200, 0, .66, 0);
  vertex(250, 200, .83, 1);
  vertex(300, 0, 1, 0);
  vertex(300, 200, 1, 1);

  endShape();
}
```

[image]

You can play around with it to get the exact effect you're looking for, but following these steps should be your general approach. Note that you only need to use a single image, and you need to figure out the `u` and `v` values for every vertex you draw on screen. Start with a triangle mesh that displays the image normally, and then modify that to morph your image.

Also note that I could have done a lot of this calculation programatically. For example, instead of hard-coding the value `150`, I could have used `width/2.0`. But first you need to understand the relationship between the `x,y` on screen and the `u,v` in the texture. Once you understand that relationship, you can calculate them programatically if you want.

Comment: Thanks a loooooooooot ^_^